# ARC: Does New Document Need to Have a Strong Pointer to It?

Tags: xcode, cocoa, automatic-ref-counting

I've just ported my app from Garbage Collection to ARC using the Xcode tool. When my app creates a new window, the window immediately vanishes. Under GC, the window remained visible.

I understand that in ARC, any object that doesn't have a strong pointer to it disappears. I have a strong pointer from my NSDocument-subclass object to the window that belongs to it, but the NSWindow disappears immediately after being created anyway.

Do I need to have a strong pointer to the new NSDocument-subclass object? And if so, what does that pointer belong to?

```
- (IBAction)importLegacyDocument:(id)sender{
    myDocument* theDocument = [[myDocument alloc]init];

    NSWindowController* theWindowController;
    theWindowController =[[NSWindowController alloc]
                          initWithWindowNibName:@"myDocument" owner: theDocument];
    [theDocument makeWindowControllers];
    [theDocument showWindows];
//WINDOW VANISHES IMMEDIATELY AFTER IT HAS BEEN CREATED
}
```

Thanks very much in advance to all for any info!

Comment: It sounds like you may have changed something in the transition as moving from GC to ARC should be really easy - if you don't reference something in either it is collected/released, they both are effectively based on a notion of strong pointers. So in general if your document survived under GC it should do so under ARC. Its probably worth you checking that something less obvious hasn't accidentally changed causing your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, and the correct place for that strong reference is the nsdocumentcontroller singleton.

You should create new documents using nsdocumentcontroller's methods rather than alloc/init. This will automatically add new documents to the document controller and remove them when the document is closed.

Comment: Thanks very much, Chris! Looking at sample code (e.g. iSpend) it looks like a) I don't have to create an NSDocumentController -- it is already created for me. And b) I don't have to maintain a pointer to NSDocumentController. I can just access it any time I want via  NSDocumentController *controller = [NSDocumentController sharedDocumentController];  Is this correct?

Comment: That's right. There is one instance, which is created and retained for you.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you should have a reference to the document. Any objects you create inside a method will be destroyed if there are not being retained. The same goes for your `NSWindowController` instance in that code as well.

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) myDocument *theDocument;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSWindowController *theWindowController
```

(Your `AppDelegate` would be a good place to declare those properties)

Then assign the created instances to your properties:

```
self.theDocument = [[myDocument alloc] init];
self.theWindowController = [[NSWindowController alloc] initWithWindowNibName:@"myDocument" owner:self.theDocument];
```

And as a side note - The Objective-C convention is to name classes with uppercase letters so *myDocument* should be *MyDocument*

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks! That's very helpful. What is the correct way to set  self.theDocument to nil when the document window is closed?

Comment: @user364966, take a look at Chris's answer below. He has suggested a better way to use NSDocumentController. I was only talking about general memory management in regards to your question.